# Measure-Preserving Transformations from R^D to R^d (d < D)

Tags: measure-theory, manifolds, change-of-variable

If we have a variable $X \in R^n$ (like an image) and a non-linear, invertible function $F: X \rightarrow H$ that maps $R^n$ to $R^d$ with $(d<n)$, how can I learn a F that preserves measure?

Particularly, if $X$ follows a probability distribution $p(X)$, can I analytically compute $p(X)$ from $p(H)$ using change-of-variables formula?

In my problem, F is a [normalizing flow](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13913) composed by a series of $k$ invertible transformations $f_k: R^n \rightarrow R^n$, and a function $proj(H)$ that takes only d components of it.
Next, I have another normalizing flow $G: proj(H) \rightarrow Z$, with $p(Z)$ defined as $\mathbf{N}(0,I)$, and trained by minimizing negative log-likelihood.

How can I restrict F and G to preserve measure?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks! I typed the question in a rush, just fixed.